# Чи можна "мафін" назвати "кекс"?

Tags: вживання-слів, відповідник

На [Словотвір](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/mafin) пропонують "мафін" замінити відповідником "кекс". Проте визначення в СУМ-20 дещо різняться.

> [Мафін](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=202855&page=1585) а, ч. Маленька кругла або овальна випічка, перев. солодка,
>   з різноманітною начинкою.
>
> [Кекс](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=41369&page=1306) у, ч. Кондитерський виріб із здобного тіста з родзинками у
>   вигляді хлібця або булочки.

Чи можна вважати слово *"кекс"* абсолютним відповідником *"мафін"*? Чи можемо вживати обидва слова як синоніми або варто розмежовувати ці значення?

Comment: Такі речі, мабуть, варто дивитися в спеціалізованих (кулінарних) джерелах, тлумачні словники до таких речей можуть підходити надто поверхнево. [Російська Вікіпедія](//ru.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Маффин&oldid=92513913) пише, що мафін — «американський варіант кексу», [українська](//uk.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Мафін&oldid=20051225) наразі не пише (хоча це теж не спеціалізовані джерела). В будь-якому разі, це не повністю еквівалентні поняття, навіть якщо вони частково перетинаються чи одне з них є частковим випадком іншого.

Comment: До речі, навіть якщо підходити пуристично, то я не бачу причин замінювати _мафін_ на _кекс_, бо _кекс_ — теж запозичення, причому теж з англійської (від _cake(s)_).

Answer (score 3):

## Коротко

Попереџаю, я далеко не кухар, але швидкиј прогляд з анґліјської мови вказує на такиј порядок:

- *Кекс* — збірне і широке понятє, хоча наша мова для широкого загалу дешчо [звузила](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81) переважно до ріжновиду *пирогів*. Коли казати про чистомовства, то декілька џерел ([Штепа](//archive.org/stream/shtepa1977/shtepa1977_djvu.txt), [Вікі](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%BE)) раять *тістечко*.
- *Mафін* — понятє, шчо входить під *кекс*. Коли брати анґліјську вимову, правильніше *мафин*, однак за чинним правописом все так.

Себто [сливе] кожен *мафин* = *кекс*, але не кожен *кекс* = *мафином*. Сє як кожниј *карась* = *риба*, але не завше навпаки. Однак способи приготуваня швидші і масовіші, аніж розвиток рибини природою, тому і приписав «сливе», оскільки можливі відхиленя: *мафин* залишаєть ся *мафином*, але вже не дуже нагадує звичаєвого *кексу*, а вже скоріш ріжновиду *хлїба*.

Тому бува можна ӥх вживати як сутямки, однак не завше варто.

## Означеня

Візьму для прикладу најпровідніші словники:

[Cambridge](//dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/muffin), [MacMillan](//macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/muffin)

> a small sweet *cake* that often contains fruit

[Oxford](//en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/muffin)

> A small domed spongy *cake* made with eggs and baking powder.

Про сливе:

MacMillan

> a flat round type of *bread*, usually cut in half and eaten hot with butter. The American word is English muffin.

Cambridge

> English muffin a small round flat type of *bread*, usually sliced in two and eaten hot with butter

Oxford

> A flat circular spongy *bread* roll made from yeast dough and eaten split, toasted, and buttered.

Також *мафин* [входить](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cakes) до переліку ріжновидів *кексів*.

Точного похоџеня слова *мафин* не дуже відоме, але є [наукова думка](//etymonline.com/word/muffin):

> "light, small cake made with eggs," 1703, *moofin*, possibly from Low German *muffen*, plural of *muffe* "small cake;" or somehow connected with Old French *moflet* "soft, tender" (said of bread). *Muffin top* in reference to waistline bulge over tight, low jeans is attested by 2005, from resemblance to baked muffins from a tin.

Себто де першоџерельні слова мали словникові описи: *кекс* чи шчось до *хлїбу*.

Answer (score -2):

Почнемо з того, що кекс — це також запозичене слово, що походить від англійського "cake" (як було зазначено в коментарях та на самому [Словотворі](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/mafin)).

А от і пояснення із [кулінарного сайту](http://makeupyourmindez.blogspot.com/2017/09/difference-between-muffins-and-cupcakes.html), де є питання про різницю між "мафінами" та "кексами":

> Через зовнішній вигляд мафіни часто називають кексами. Але це не
>   коректно, хоча й набір продуктів для їхнього приготування майже
>   однаковий. В одному з випусків "Все буде смачно" кондитер Ліза
>   Глінська казала, що кекси та капкейки — це бісквітне тісто, а мафіни —
>   хлібне. В свою чергу капкейк — це той же торт, кекс або тістечко
>   невеликого розміру у порційному форматі. Кекси та капкейки можуть
>   прикрашатися, а мафіни — ні, адже мафін — це маленький хлібчик.

Про те, що це зовсім різна випічна я знайшов і на [цьому російському сайті](http://edalegko.ru/poleznosti/chem-otlichaetsya-maffin-ot-keksa/):

> Однак, якщо прискіпливо дивитися на питання із теоретичної точки зору, то 
>   кекси
>   і мафіни — це зовсім різна випічка, і різниця між ними прихована в основі
>   основ - методі замішування тіста.

Йдеться про різницю і на [сайті](https://thedifference.ru/otlichie-keksa-ot-maffina/) про різницю між різними поняттями (також російський).

Отож, можна зробити висновок — кекс **не може** бути **абсолютним** синонімом до слова "мафін". А також, повернемося до того з чого я почав цю відповідь, а також як зазначив Олександр — Чи доцільно заміняти запозичене слово таким же запозиченим?

Comment: [Стаття на сайті «Моя освіта»](http://moyaosvita.com.ua/juzha-i-napoi/chim-vidriznyayetsya-keks-vid-maffina/) виявилася напівграмотним перекладом [цієї російської статті](https://thedifference.ru/otlichie-keksa-ot-maffina/).

Comment: Не розумію, навіщо шукати значення слів "кекс" і "мафін" на російських сайтах і в недбалих перекладах статей з тих сайтів, якщо ці слова не походять з російської мови. Поки що мінус один. Ще й тому, що нема перекладу українською цитати з εδαλεγκο.ρυ.

Comment: @P.Vovk, ну, принаймні одне українське джерело (що, до речі, посилається на інше джерело) відповідь має. Тому, по-моєму, вона не заслуговує на мінус. Щодо російських відповідників _кекс_ і _маффин_, то по-моєму, оскільки ці слова запозичені відразу декількома мовами (щонайменше: польською, рос., укр.) з одних і тих самих джерел, і значення цих слів у цих мовах можуть бути дуже близькими, то, як вторинне джерело, така інформація, мені здається, підійде (хоча подавати її треба трішки акуратніше, мовляв, «у рос. мові ці слова теж мають різне знач., хоч ситуація там й не обов. збігається з укр.»).

Comment: По-моєму, несправедливо, що ця відповідь отримала негативну оцінку.